# How to add a full stop after 'Appendix A'

Tags: appendix

I am completing my MSc thesis. I need to add an appendix section. At the moment I am using `\usepackage[title]{appendix}` and the appendices appear as 'Appendix A Derivation of LURB' But I want 'Appendix A. Derivation of LURB' Notice the full stop after Appendix A.

I have the following code in my main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
    \input{LUBR}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

and in the LURB file I have: `\section{Derivation of LURB}`

Comment: The answer might depend (a lot) on the used `\documentclass`.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}

Comment: @Andy It is very important to add a minimal working example to give you an answer.

Comment: Try \appendixpage (page 2 of appendix manual).

Comment: This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your `\begin{appendices}` add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}`
like this

```
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}
...
```

noting the period (full stop).

Comment: This works. However, when referencing equations inside the appendix they will be of the form (A..1) which is inconvenient. To change this add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}`  before the appendix title and `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`  after appendix title.